# In Python, variables inside if conditions hide the global scope even if they are not executed?

Tags: python

```
def do_something():
    print 'doing something...'

def maybe_do_it(hesitant=False):
    if hesitant:
        do_something = lambda: 'did nothing'
    result = do_something()
    print result

maybe_do_it()
```

The result of this code is:

```
  File "scope_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    maybe_do_it()
  File "scope_test.py", line 7, in maybe_do_it
    result = do_something()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'do_something' referenced before assignment
```

But this code prints "did something..." as expected:

```
def do_something():
    print 'doing something...'

def maybe_do_it(hesitant=False):
    result = do_something()
    print result

maybe_do_it()
```

How did the function get overridden even though the condition inside the if statement never executed?  This happens in Python 2.7 -- is it the same in Python 3?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question Quote: "Python treats variables in functions differently depending on whether you assign values to them from within the function or not."

Comment: @flornquake Yes, but when did I assign a value to that variable? Was the variable assigned in the code that never executed?

Comment: @Buttons840, if you have any assignment to this some variable in function then local variable will shadow global.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How did the function get overridden even though the condition inside the if statement never executed?

The decision whether the variable is local or global is made at compile time.  If there is an assignment to a variable anywhere in the function, it's a local variable, no matter if the assignment is ever executed.

> This happens in Python 2.7 -- is it the same in python 3?

Yes.

By the way, in Python 2, you can override this behavior by using `exec` (not recommended):

```
def do_something():
    print 'doing something...'

def maybe_do_it(hesitant=False):
    if hesitant:
        exec "do_something = lambda: 'did nothing'"
    result = do_something()
    print result

maybe_do_it(False)    # doing something...
maybe_do_it(True)    # did nothing
```

An `exec` inside a function will, loosely speaking, postpone the decision whether to look up the variable globally or locally to execution time.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Maybe it shouldn't spend so much time on the hacky `exec` workaround, but it explicitly says that isn't recommended, and it only gets into that at all after correctly explaining what happens.

Comment: +1; not because i think this is at all a good way to solve this problem, its a bad one; but because I learned something.  the exec here gets causes the final return to be compiled to `LOAD_NAME` instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL`

Answer (score 6):

As stated in documentation of [Python Execution Model](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, 
>      all uses of the name within the block are treated as references 
>      to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used 
>      within a block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python 
>      lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur 
>      anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block 
>      can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name
>      binding operations.

This is a rule of the language. That is just the way it is. :D

Comment: The nice thing about this answer is that it correctly implies that the exact same thing will happen even in a Python implementation that _doesn't_ compile to bytecode the way CPython does. But I think the other two answers' explanations in term of compilation are helpful to understanding things, as long as you keep in mind that they're just describing CPython.

Answer (score 1):

When python compiles to bytecode (makes the `*.pyc` file)* as there is a `do_something = lambda: 'did nothing'` line in your function `do_something` is now treated as a local variable, even if the control flow doesn't take the interpreter there.

The main reasons this is unexpected is that :

1. Contrary to common belief, [Python is compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both)
2. It's unintuitive.

Fundamentally I think this only becomes a problem if you're implementing bad design. When you reassign `do_something` from within a function you are playing with the global scope - this is rarely a good idea.

*As has been pointed out, this doesn't actually only apply to Python which is compiled to bytecode (CPython) - it's actually a feature of the language. The details of my explanation (Expressing in terms of bytecode) refers only to CPython.

Comment: My understanding of the world is shaken... :(

Comment: Cheer up! It's not as bad as all that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the same in Python 3. For the most part this is desirable, if not entirely intuitive behavior. [Perhaps you have to be Dutch](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Many people may be familiar with hoisting (popularized by JavaScript?). It happens in Python, too, except that instead of having an `undefined` value, Python just raises an `UnboundLocalError`. Compare:

```
> // JavaScript example
> var x = 1;
> function foo() {
    if (!x) { // x is declared locally below, so locally x is undefined
      var x = 2;
    }
    return x;
  }
> foo();
2

>>> # Everything else is Python 3
>>> x = 1
>>> def foo():
...   if not x: # x is bound below, which constitutes declaring it as a local
...     x = 2
...   return x
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

So far Python's consistent, but there's a (troubling) workaround:

```
>>> def foo():
...   if not 'x' in locals():
...     x = 2
...   return x
... 
>>> foo()
2
```

That works, and we've [been told](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

> The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.

But doesn't `locals()` give us all the local names? Evidently not. In fact, despite the previous statement, Python hints that the local symbol table can change in [the description of the `locals()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals):

> Update and return a dictionary representing the *current* [emphasis mine] local symbol table.

I used to think the word *current* referred to the values, now I think it refers to the keys as well. But ultimately what I think this means is there's *no way* (short of dumping and parsing the source code for a frame) to enumerate all the names that are declared locally (which is not to say you can't use try/except UnboundLocalError to determine if a specific name is local.)

```
def foo():
    # Some code, including bindings
    del x, y, z # or any other local names
    # From this point, is it programmatically knowable what names are local?
```

This, I think, is a fundamental difference between a language with implicit declarations and a language with explicit ones.