# exec statement changes LOAD_GLOBAL to LOAD_NAME?

Tags: python

In studying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647337/65696), I discoved, much to my surprise, that `exec` has a strange behavior;

```
>>> def f1():
...     return x
... 
>>> def f2():
...     exec ""
...     return x
... 
>>> f1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
>>> f2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x = 'bar'
>>> f1()
'bar'
>>> f2()
'bar'
```

Obviously, both return some global value `x`; but not so if `f2()` is changed slightly:

```
>>> def f2():
...     exec "x = 'im local now'"
...     return x
... 
>>> f2()
'im local now'
```

f2 returns its own special copy of `x`, even though there's nothing in the body of f2 that would seem to cause that (no assignment to x).

I can easy see how this is happening, the presence of the `exec` statement changes the `LOAD_GLOBAL` bytecode into a `LOAD_NAME`, in a similar vein as the presence of `yield` turns a function into a generator.

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 EXEC_STMT           

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

But what I don't understand is *why*.  Is this documented behavior?  is this an implementation detail of cpython? (it works in the same way in IronPython, although the `dis` module is non functional)

Comment: Your first `f2` also seems to be returning a local `x`.

Comment: Doesn't this statement in the documentation of [exec](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec) explain this behavior: "In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope."

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a more general case:

```
def f(stuff):
    exec(stuff)
    return x
```

Python obviously has to use `LOAD_NAME` here, because it doesn't know whether the code in `stuff` will mess with `x`. The same case goes for *any* use of `exec()`, even if the argument is a constant — Python simply doesn't do a deep enough analysis to determine that any `exec()` happens to be safe.

(There's a perfectly good reason why it shouldn't do that analysis, too: the only case that it *could* even analyze with any degree of success would be `exec()` on a constant argument, which is pointless. If the argument is fully known ahead of time, it should just be normal code!)

Comment: `exec` isn't a function in Python 2. In Python 3, it's a function, but it doesn't affect the bytecode generated.