# Why does Python report syntax errors before their execution point is reached?

Tags: python

Python is an interpreted language so it execute the code line by line so when I am running

```
import csv,re,sys

print len(sys.argv)
if(len(sys.argv)!=2):
    sys.exit(0)

filename= #from command line argument
```

it doesn't execute even a single line and give syntax error.

Now my question is that last line of the code has error but python interpreter execute the code line by line so the code up to the last line is correct so it should execute the code upto the last line but it is giving me the below error and not printing length of sys.argv that I have defined in line 2

```
File "trace-analysis.py", line 45
filename = # from command line argument
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not getting this behaviour....
please someone explain this ...

Comment: why negative point is given?

Comment: Just because code is **executed** line-by-line doesn't mean it's **parsed** line-by-line.

Comment: Your predicate is incorrect.

Comment: filename is any csv file like analyse.csv...

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Python interpreted or compiled or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both)

Answer (score 7):

> python interpreter execute the code line by line

**This is *false*!!!**

Python reads *the whole* file, *compiles* it to bytecode and then executes the bytecode.
If there is a syntax error *anywhere* in the file *no* instruction is run because the interpreter will first try to *parse* the whole contents of the file and realize it's not a well-formed program.

Python is not bash.

---

Just ot be clear what I mean with the last statement:

```
$echo 'print("Hello, World!")
> $(
> ' > test.py
$python test.py   # NOTE: no Hello, World in the output
  File "test.py", line 2
    $(
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$echo 'echo "Hello, World!"
$(
' > test.sh
$bash test.sh    # NOTE: there's a Hello, World => bash execute the first statement!
Hello, World!
test.sh: riga 2: EOF non atteso durante la ricerca di ")"
test.sh: riga 4: errore di sintassi: EOF non atteso
```

<sup>My locale is italian. The error is just a standard error message saying that it found an unexpected EOF.</sup>

Hence bash does *not* parse the whole file before starting execution. *Quod est demostrandum*

Comment: bash actually doesn't do strict line-by-line parsing and execution either.

Comment: Demonstrably false: It's lookahead in the parser that was responsible for one of the more interesting security bugs of late.

Comment: @MarkReed That was my point. Write a script that starts with `echo "Hello, World"` and then contains crap and bash will happily output `Hello, World`. Python doesn't.

Comment: yes... thanks a lot to correcting me ..... My concept was full wrong.... but Really I didn't know the concept that's why put the question here.... I don't know why people give negative rating... kk no worry.. don't bother about rating.. atleast I have learned something new.... again thanks a lot

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you point out where did I state that bash executes line by line? My statement is *Python isn't bash* and my whole answer **never** mentions "line-by-line" behaviour. I believe the point I wanted to make is perfectly clear, but if you want an example I can provide one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used the wrong term. It doesn't have forward declarations - you can't call a function before you declare it.  (You can declare a function containing calls to as-yet-undeclared functions, though.)

Comment: And they both do (mostly) line-by-line at the REPL. :)

Comment: @MarkReed, that's... dependent on how one defines things; you can certainly define your functions out-of-order (which many explicitly single-pass-compiled languages _don't_ allow), and can certainly define stubs and replace them with full definitions later. To be sure, there's no implicit reordering as you get with proper two-pass compilation, and the only reason one can get away with some of the above is the lack of any kind of reference checking at definition time.

Comment: @Bakuriu, "Python is not bash" as a refutation to a claim that Python parses and executes code in a strictly line-by-line manner reads to me as an unambiguous implication that bash executes code line-by-line. Which is close, but not _quite_ unambiguously true.

Comment: Re: recent edits -- I never claimed that bash _did_ parse an entire file as code before running it, by the way. If it did, quite a number of tools (shar archives, for instance) would be useless.