# Accessing variables defined in enclosing scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Lexical_Scoping) on lexical scoping:

> A nested Python function can refer to variables defined in enclosing
>   functions, but can not assign to them.

Both of these seem to check out at first:

```
# Reference
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        print(a + 2)
    nested()
    return a
toplevel()
7
Out[]: 5

# Assignment
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        a = 7 # a is still 5, can't modify enclosing scope variable
    nested()
    return a
toplevel()
Out[]: 5
```

So why, then, does a combination of both reference and assignment in the nested function lead to an exception?

```
# Reference and assignment
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        print(a + 2)
        a = 7
    nested()
    return a
toplevel()
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Just a note, the `print(a+2);a=7` combination doesn't work, however, the `a=7;print(a+2)` combination works.

Comment: The guide in question is, to my understanding, written for Python 2.x, which lacks the `nonlocal` keyword. In 3.x, `nonlocal` can be used to work around the problem described.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In first case, you are referring to a `nonlocal` variable which is ok because there is no local variable called `a`.

```
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        print(a + 2) # theres no local variable a so it prints the nonlocal one
    nested()
    return a
```

In the second case, you create a local variable `a` which is also fine (local `a` will be different than the nonlocal one thats why the original `a` wasn't changed).

```
def toplevel():
    a = 5 
    def nested():
        a = 7 # create a local variable called a which is different than the nonlocal one
        print(a) # prints 7
    nested()
    print(a) # prints 5
    return a
```

In the third case, you create a local variable but you have `print(a+2)` before that and that is why the exception is raised. Because `print(a+2)` will refer to the local variable `a` which was created after that line.

```
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        print(a + 2) # tries to print local variable a but its created after this line so exception is raised
        a = 7
    nested()
    return a
toplevel()
```

To achieve what you want, you need to use `nonlocal a` inside your inner function:

```
def toplevel():
    a = 5
    def nested():
        nonlocal a
        print(a + 2)
        a = 7
    nested()
    return a
```

Comment: In the third case, how does `nested` "know" to search for a local variable rather than use the enclosing function's `a`? I follow your answer otherwise, but not this aspect since python is interpreted line by line.

Comment: Even though its an interpreted language, the whole syntax gets checked before it runs. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889798/7688996) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263982/why-is-python-treated-as-a-interpreted-language-when-it-has-a-compiling-stage)

Comment: @BradSolomon Python's semantics don't depend on it being interpreted. Even CPython, the canonical, "interpreting" implementation of Python, does not "interpret line by line". It **compiles** the text of the program into bytecode, and that bytecode then runs on the cpython virtual machine (VM). The bytecode is machine code for a particular "CPU" that is the cpython VM.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone stumbling across this question, in addition to the accepted answer here, it is answered concisely in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value):

> This code:
>
> ```
> >>> x = 10
> >>> def bar():
> ...     print(x)
> >>> bar()
> 10
> ```
>
> works, but this code:
>
> ```
> >>> x = 10
> >>> def foo():
> ...     print(x)
> ...     x += 1
> ```
>
> results in an `UnboundLocalError`.
>
> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope,
>   that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly
>   named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo
>   assigns a new value to `x`, the compiler recognizes it as a local
>   variable. Consequently when the earlier `print(x)` attempts to print the
>   uninitialized local variable and an error results.
>
> In the example above you can access the outer scope variable by
>   declaring it `global`:
>
> ```
> >>> x = 10
> >>> def foobar():
> ...     global x
> ...     print(x)
> ...     x += 1
> >>> foobar()
> 10
> ```
>
> You can do a similar thing in a nested scope using the `nonlocal`
>   keyword:
>
> ```
> >>> def foo():
> ...    x = 10
> ...    def bar():
> ...        nonlocal x
> ...        print(x)
> ...        x += 1
> ...    bar()
> ...    print(x)
> >>> foo()
> 10
> 11
> ```