# Using the variable type annotation as a placeholder in a nonlocal scope?

Tags: python, scope, annotations, python-3.6, python-nonlocal

Since [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#specification) was approved, in Python 3.6+ it is possible to provide type hint information in the form **`x: int`**, also the PEP says *"However, annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to always make it local to the scope and leaves the variable uninitialized"*. Therefore in Python 3.6+ it is syntactically *legal* to write:

```
def outer():
    x: int
    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = 10
    inner()
    print(x)
```

while the above snippet is semantically more equivalent to:

```
def outer():
    #x 
    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = 10
    inner()
    print(x)
```

Which is obviously a **`SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found`**, sorry for the pun. Also there is nothing said about this style in PEP 8 and Python 3.6 docs.

***So should I consider this as a bug, or an implementation detail (side effect), or a wart, or a feature?***

After some googling on the web, I found that this effect is already used in stdlib - **`typing.NamedTuple`** but actually class bodies are not scopes and also this effect seems to be exploited in Python 3.7 **`@dataclasses`**. This situation really surprises me, it turns out that some things can not be done without **`type annotations`**, while their only intention was to provide type hints without any run-time or compile-time effects.

Relatively **`nonlocal`** part, this question is pretty close to:

1. [When existence of nonlocal variables is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814787/when-existence-of-nonlocal-variables-is-checked)
2. [Accessing variables defined in enclosing scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018872/accessing-variables-defined-in-enclosing-scope)

and from this perspective it can be closed. In fact we can not come to a consensus and I would like to hear your thoughts of possible pitfalls, if any, if we choose to use this form in our codebase.

Comment: I apologize if the question is an off-topic for SO.

Comment: like this https://bugs.python.org/issue32361 ?

Comment: After rereading, I think this is a similar but not same issue https://bugs.python.org/issue32361 .  They talk about the implementation logic being correct.  Are you thinking that the implementation should not occur or that the error is not sufficient or something else?