# How are python closures implemented?

Tags: python, closures

I am interested in how python implements closures?

For the sake of example, consider this

```py
def closure_test():
    x = 1
    def closure():
        nonlocal x
        x = 2
        print(x)
    return closure

closure_test()()
```

Here, the function `closure_test` has a local `x` which the nested function `closure` captures.

When I run the program, I get the following output

```py
2
```

When I see the disassembly of the function `closure_test`,

```py
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object closure at 0x7f14ac3b9500, file "<string>", line 3>)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('closure_test.<locals>.closure')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (closure)

  7          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (closure)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object closure at 0x7f14ac3b9500, file "<string>", line 3>:
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (x)

  6           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              6 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

I see the instructions `STORE_DEREF`, `LOAD_DEREF`, `MAKE_FUNCTION` and `LOAD_CLOSURE` which I won't get if I write the whole program without functions and closures.

I think those are the instructions which are needed to use closures.

But how does Python manages this? How does it captures the variable off from the local variable table of the enclosing function? And after capturing the variable where does it live? How does the function get the access of the captured variable?

I want a complete low level understanding of how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Overview

Python doesn't directly use *variables* the same way one might expect coming from a statically-typed language like C or Java, rather it uses *names* and tags instances of objects with them

In your example, `closure` is simply an instance of a function with that name

It's really `nonlocal` here which causes `LOAD_CLOSURE` and `BUILD_TUPLE` to be used as described in [When is the existence of nonlocal variables checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814787/when-is-the-existence-of-nonlocal-variables-checked) and further in [How to define free-variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919278/how-to-define-free-variable-in-python) and refers to `x`, not the inner function named literally `closure`

```
  3           4 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
```

#### About `nonlocal`

For your case, `nonlocal` is asserting that `x` exists in the outer scope excluding globals at compile time, but is practically redundant because it's not used elsewhere [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)
**Originally I'd written that this was redundant due to redeclaration, but that's not true - `nonlocal` *prevents* re-using the name, but `x` simply isn't shown anywhere else so the effect isn't obvious**
I've added a 3rd example with a very ugly generator to illustrate the effect

Example of use with a global (note the `SyntaxError` is at compile time, not at runtime!)

```py
>>> x = 3
>>> def closure_test():
...     def closure():
...         nonlocal x
...         print(x)
...     return closure
...
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found
>>> def closure_test():
...     def closure():
...         print(x)
...     return closure
...
>>> closure_test()()
3
```

Examples of `SyntaxError`s related to invalid locals use

```py
>>> def closure_test():
...     def closure():
...         nonlocal x
...         x = 2
...         print(x)
...     return closure
...
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found
>>> def closure_test():
...     x = 1
...     def closure():
...         x = 2
...         nonlocal x
...         print(x)
...     return closure
...
  File "<stdin>", line 5
SyntaxError: name 'x' is assigned to before nonlocal declaration
```

Example which makes use of `nonlocal` to set the outer value
(Note this is badly-behaved because a more normal approach wrapping `yield` with `try:finally` displays *before* `closure` is actually called)

```py
>>> def closure_test():
...     x = 1
...     print(f"x outer A: {x}")
...     def closure():
...         nonlocal x
...         x = 2
...         print(f"x inner: {x}")
...     yield closure
...     print(f"x outer B: {x}")
...
>>> list(x() for x in closure_test())
x outer A: 1
x inner: 2
x outer B: 2
[None]
```

Original Example without `nonlocal` (note absence of `BUILD_TUPLE` and `LOAD_CLOSURE`!)

```py
>>> def closure_test():
...     x = 1
...     def closure():
...         x = 2
...         print(x)
...     return closure
...
>>>
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(closure_test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object closure at 0x10d8132f0, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('closure_test.<locals>.closure')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (closure)

  6          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (closure)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object closure at 0x10d8132f0, file "<stdin>", line 3>:
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

#### About the ByteCode and a Simple Comparison

Reducing your example to remove all the names, it's simply

```py
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: print(2))
 ​1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             ​2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             ​4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             ​6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The rest of the bytecode just moves the names around

- `x` for `1` and `2`
- `closure` and `closure_test.<locals>.closure` for inner function (located at some memory address)
- `print` literally the print function
- `None` literally the `None` singleton

Specific DIS opcodes

- [`STORE_DEREF`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_DEREF) puts a value in slot `i`
- [`LOAD_DEREF`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF) retrieves a value from slot `i`
- [`MAKE_FUNCTION`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-MAKE_FUNCTION) creates a new function on the stack and puts it in slot `i`
- [`LOAD_CLOSURE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CLOSURE) does just that, putting it on the stack at `i`

---

You can see the constants, names, and free variables with `dis.show_code()`

```py
>>> dis.show_code(closure_test)
Name:              closure_test
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    0
Positional-only arguments: 0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  1
Stack size:        3
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS
Constants:
  ​0: None
  ​1: 1
  ​2: <code object closure at 0x10db282f0, file "<stdin>", line 3>
  ​3: 'closure_test.<locals>.closure'
Variable names:
  ​0: closure
Cell variables:
  ​0: x
```

Digging at the closure itself

```py
>>> dis.show_code(closure_test())  # call outer
Name:              closure
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    0
Positional-only arguments: 0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  0
Stack size:        2
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NESTED
Constants:
  ​0: None
  ​1: 2
Names:
  ​0: print
Free variables:
  ​0: x
>>> dis.show_code(lambda: print(2))
Name:              <lambda>
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    0
Positional-only arguments: 0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  0
Stack size:        2
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
  ​0: None
  ​1: 2
Names:
  ​0: print
```

---

Using Python 3.9.10

Other related questions

- [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)
- [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals)

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful