# Opencv in a Docker Environment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cv2' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I am trying to use opencv in a server (Docker) environment. In my requirements file I have `opencv-python-headless==4.8.1.78`

In my script I `import cv2` but line items like `image = cv2.imread(inputfile)` return an error that suggests that the cv2 import was unsuccessful:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cv2' referenced before assignment
```

Im sure this is due to my misunderstanding of the headless package vs. what I am importing but I am unfamiliar with the calls and am unsure of how to resolve it.

```
python: 3.9.13
```

Comment: [mre] required. yes, that includes a simple python file that _produces_ the error. including traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in a function, you're assigning to `cv2`, which unbinds the name in the local function context, leading to the error

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> def foo():
...     cv2.imread()
...     cv2 = "something"  # <-- this is what causes error
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cv2' referenced before assignment
```

This Question about `nonlocal` or some of its ending links may be more enlightening: [How are python closures implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773695/how-are-python-closures-implemented) (full disclosure, that's my Answer!)

Comment: I do just double checked my work and I dont believe I am assigning anything to cv2 elsewhere

Comment: hmm.. the traceback should show some context about where this happens, it could be something you're importing has an error .. or some `grep 'cv2 =' ./` may be sufficient to find it

Comment: if this really doesn't come from user code, it might be coming from opencv's peculiar way of loading the library files. that would have to happen at `import` time, not after. since I can't find this error message anywhere in opencv's github, not as any reported issue, that too is unlikely to be the source. more debugging info required.