# Accessing variables in enclosing scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

**NOTE**: Please read the full question before tagging this as a duplicate of [Accessing variables defined in enclosing scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018872/accessing-variables-defined-in-enclosing-scope).

Why is it possible to use a nonlocal dict but not a scalar value within a closure in python? For example:

```
def something():
    SCALAR = 0
    DICT = {0:0}
    def _inner():
        SCALAR += 1 # no
        DICT[0] += 1 # yes
```

Comment: I said that you could edit the other question to explain what's the difference.

Comment: Besides "NOTE: please read the full question" won't end well. Explaining is properly like you did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309513/python-global-vs-dict#comment117229297_66309513 is better.

Comment: To complete your example (i.e. show the error), you need to call to _inner inside function something.

Comment: Short explanation: because `x += y` involves an *assignment* to the variable `x`, hence marking that `x` as *local*. On the other hand, `x[i] += y` *does not involve an assignment to `x`* The **types** of the object being referred to *are completely irrelevant*. For example, try `x = [0]` and then in `_inner`, `x[0] += 1` will work, but `x += [1]` will fail

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Re the duplicate: OP's issue in this case is that they want an explanation on why the dict assignment **works**. (I can find some for global, see the other post)

Comment: yes; and the reason the dict assignment works is because it's *not an assignment*, but a modification of the dict. Python recognizes the `x[y] = z` pattern differently from `x = y` in the grammar (it must, in order to be able to reroute to `x.__setitem__(y, z)`; and in so doing, that changes the *compile-time* rule for whether `x` is deemed a local. I edited the duplicate link to something that should be more precise.