# UnboundLocalError: local variable <function> referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

I have read similar questions on this topic such as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018872/accessing-variables-defined-in-enclosing-scope), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-after-an-if-sta), and others on scope, but I still cannot understand why answers do not explain these test cases.

First see this:

```py
def take_sum(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

def main():
    print("take_sum" in globals())
    print(take_sum(1,2,3))

main()
```

Returns:

```
True
6
```

So then this must work:

```py
# TEST 1

def take_sum(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

def main():
    if "take_sum" not in globals():
        take_sum = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c

    print(take_sum)

main()
```

WRONG!

Returns: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'take_sum' referenced before assignment`

**Question 1**: How is `take_sum` referenced before assignment if it exists in the global scope and the if-statement in `main` evalutes to False?

So let's add an `else` clause to the if-statement:

```py
# TEST 2

def take_sum(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

def main():
    if "take_sum" not in globals():
        take_sum = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c

    else:
        global take_sum

    print(take_sum)

main()
```

Returns: `SyntaxError: name 'take_sum' is assigned to before global declaration`

**Question 2**: But how is this possible if the error from TEST 1 says `take_sum` was referenced but NOT assigned?

Subsequently, switching the clauses in the if-statement works:

```py
# TEST 3

def take_sum(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

def main():
    if "take_sum" in globals():
        global take_sum

    elif "take_sum" not in globals():
        take_sum = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c

    print(take_sum)
    print(take_sum(1,2,3))

main()
```

Returns:

```
<function take_sum at 0x7fbf8b5bb160>
6
```

**Question 3**: Why does switching clauses (compared to TEST 2) work?

Comment: "How is take_sum referenced before assignment if it exists in the global scope and the if-statement in main evalutes to False?" In the same way as in the first link you found: the existence in global scope is **not relevant**, because there is assignment **code**, the **presence of which** is checked **ahead of time**. It **does not matter** that the conditional code doesn't run, **just like** it didn't matter, for that question, that the assignment happens after the usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a name used in a function is a global variable or a local one is determined at compile time, not at run time. Your functions that cause exceptions are trying to have it both ways, to either access a global, or provide their own local variable replacement, but Python's scoping rules don't allow that. It needs to be local or global, and can't be in a nebulous either/or state.

In your Test 1, the function raises an exception because the compiler saw that the code *could* assign to `take_sum` as a local variable, and so it makes all the references to `take_sum` in the code be local. You can no longer look up the global variable `take_sum` in the normal way once that determination has been made.

A `global` statement is in effect a compiler directive to change the assumption that an assignment makes a variable local. Subsequent assignments will be made globally, not locally. It's not something that executes at runtime, which is why your other two test cases are so confusing to you.

Test 2 fails because you're trying to tell the compiler that `take_sum` is a global *after* it has already seen some of your code make a local assignment to that name. In Test 3, the `global` statement comes first, so it makes the assignment (in the other branch!) assign to a global variable. It doesn't actually matter that the `global` statement was in a different branch than the assignment, the compiler interprets the `global` statement at compile time, not at runtime when the conditional logic of the `if`s and `elif`s gets handled.

It might help your understanding of what is going on to disassemble some of the `main` functions you've written using the `dis.dis` function in the standard library. You'll see that there are two different sets of bytecodes used for loading and storing of variables, `LOAD_GLOBAL`/`STORE_GLOBAL` for global variables (used in all your functions to get names like `print` and `globals`), and `LOAD_FAST`/`STORE_FAST` which are used for local variables (like `a`, `b` and `c` in `take_sum`). The compiler behavior I talked about above boils down to which bytecode it chooses for each lookup or assignment.

If I rename the `main` function in Test 1 to `test1`, here's what I get when I disassemble it:

```
dis.dis(test1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('take_sum')
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (globals)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 CONTAINS_OP              1
              8 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       18

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <lambda> at 0x0000019022A05F50, file "<ipython-input-23-0cc3c65f7038>", line 3>)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 ('test1.<locals>.<lambda>')
             14 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (take_sum)

  5     >>   18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             20 LOAD_FAST                0 (take_sum)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x0000019022A05F50, file "<ipython-input-23-0cc3c65f7038>", line 3>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that the lookup of `take_sum` on line 5 is on byte 20 in the bytecode, where it uses `LOAD_FAST`. This is the bytecode that causes the `UnboundLocalError`, since there has been no local assigned if the global function exists.

Now, lets look at Test 3:

```
dis.dis(test3)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('take_sum')
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (globals)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 CONTAINS_OP              0
              8 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3          10 JUMP_FORWARD            18 (to 30)

  5     >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('take_sum')
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (globals)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 CONTAINS_OP              1
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30

  6          22 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <lambda> at 0x0000019022A43500, file "<ipython-input-26-887b66de7e64>", line 6>)
             24 LOAD_CONST               3 ('test3.<locals>.<lambda>')
             26 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             28 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (take_sum)

  8     >>   30 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             32 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (take_sum)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 POP_TOP

  9          38 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             40 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (take_sum)
             42 LOAD_CONST               4 (1)
             44 LOAD_CONST               5 (2)
             46 LOAD_CONST               6 (3)
             48 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             50 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             52 POP_TOP
             54 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             56 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x0000019022A43500, file "<ipython-input-26-887b66de7e64>", line 6>:
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

This time the lookup of `take_sum` happens on bytecode 40, and it's a `LOAD_GLOBAL` (which succeeds since there is a global variable of that name).

Answer (score 1):

Take this example

You're pre-defining a variable reference to be global

```
def main():
  global take_sum
  if "take_sum" not in globals():
    take_sum = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c
  print(take_sum)
```

Output: `<function main.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f08c2c54820>`

Remove, the `not`, `'take_sum' is not defined`, as expected

---

Now, create a global one

```
def take_sum(*args):
    return sum(args)

def main():
  global take_sum
  if "take_sum" not in globals():
    take_sum = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c
  print(take_sum)
```

Output this time is the outer one.

Remove the `not`, then the local one

---

So, if you try to make `global take_sum` in the else statement, then as the error says, `assigned to before global declaration`, and seems like the `global` gets evaluated without respect for the conditional

Comment: That's where I don't follow: the if-condition in TEST 1 evaluates to False, so there should be no assignment, and when the cursor returns to the print statement, it should print the location of `take_sum` in memory like in TEST 3... What am I missing

Comment: Notice that you get the same error when using `if False`. I suspect you are trying to do something very different than overriding a global function with a local one?