# Why do i need to restart Odoo when changing in python files, if python is interpreted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I've a very basic question of why odoo restart is required when making some changes in python files. I've read this https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/is-there-a-need-to-restart-openerp-server-when-we-update-a-custom-module-52293, and it says restart is mandatory but didn't say why it's mandatory.

On a running server if i can move a module to addons path and install it (without restarting server) why am i not able to modify python file and upgrade the module.

And if python is interpreted why do i need a restart?

Additionally i've even tried deleting the **pycache** directory to see if that restricts the interpreter from further compiling it, but it didn't help.

And i'm very clear that module upgradation is required if we modify xml files. No more explanation required on the same. :)

Meanwhile i'm trying to explore if i can modify the python files and tell odoo in someway other than restarting it. Thanks in advance for clarifying me.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both