# Conditional expression/ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I don't understand this syntax.

> Python program to demonstrate ternary operator

```
a, b = 10, 20
```

> Use tuple for selecting an item

```
print( (b, a) [a < b] )
```

> Use Dictionary for selecting an item

```
print({True: a, False: b} [a < b])
```

PS: I guess this is from older version of Python, because in newer versions (don't know from which version) True and False are reserved keywords, so they can't be assigned a value.

> lamda is more efficient than above two methods
>   because in lambda  we are assure that only one expression will be evaluated unlike in
>   tuple and Dictionary

```
print((lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]())
```

Syntax should be:

> [on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]

So how does

```
print( (b, a) [a < b] )
print({True: a, False: b} [a < b])
print((lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]())
```

fit this syntax?
What's the meaning of `[a<b]` after tuple/dictionary/lambda? I have never seen this syntax before. It also works when list `[b, a]` precedes `[a<b]`.

I would expect it to look like this

```
print( a if a < b else b )
```

Link to resource:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/

Comment: `True` and `False` aren't being assigned values; they are just being used as the keys of a `dict`.

Comment: That's true. I haven't realized it's just a key not assignment.

Comment: Those are alternative syntax instead of `[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]`. They use the fact that `foo = {1: "one"}` `print( foo[1] )` can be written directly as `print( {1: "one"}[1] )`

Comment: The comment about lambdas being more efficient is suspect as well. It may well be more expensive to construct two `function` objects and subsequently call one of them than it would be to simply evaluate both `a` and `b` in the first place (which happens anyway to compute `a < b`, so the entire construct is somewhat inefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that all these give the **minimum** value of `a` and `b`:

```
a, b = 10, 20

res1 = (b, a)[a < b]                    # 10
res2 = {True: a, False: b}[a < b]       # 10
res3 = (lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]()  # 10
```

We can consider these in turn:

1. `res1` constructs a `tuple` of 2 integers. `a < b` returns a Boolean value, in this case `True`. In Python, `True == 1`, as `bool` is a subclass of `int`. Finally, `[]` is syntactic sugar for `__getitem__`, which is the method called for positional indexing. Since Python starts counting from `0`, the first index is `a`. You can also confirm this yourself: `(b, a).__getitem__(1)` returns `10`.
2. `res2` constructs a dictionary mapping Boolean values to `a` & `b`. Calling `__getitem__` on a `dict` object returns the value for a given key. Here the key, as before, is `True`. Since the dictionary maps `True` to `a`, this is the value returned.
3. `res3` constructs a tuple of anonymous (`lambda`) functions, each returning scalars, namely `b` and `a`. As per `res1`, an item can be extracted from a tuple via integer indexing. The only additional requirement is to actually call the `lambda` functions via `()`.

Note none of these operate the same way as the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) which is applied <s>at compile time</s> (see comments) via an in-line `if` / `else`:

```
res4 = a if a < b else b
```

Comment: What do you mean "the ternary operator is applied at compile time"? It is a real conditional evaluated at runtime (unlike a C preprocessor #ifdef, for example).

Comment: @alexis, Python files are technically [compiled to bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889798/9209546). The bytecode is then interpreted in CPython. You are right, if I understand what you mean, that there's no compilation to machine code.

Comment: Nah, that would be splitting hairs. I mean something more relevant: A compile-time conditional chooses a branch based on what's true when the program is read/preprocessed/compiled. E.g., `#if OS == "darwin"` Then the same branch will always be followed-- in effect, the conditional is not there anymore. But a Python ternary is a real if, and will be evaluated anew (sometimes true, sometimes false) every time the program flow hits it.

Answer (score 1):

`a<b` is a `bool` (`True` or `False`). Since `bool` is a subtype of `int`, it can be used in a context where an integer is expected, e.g. as a list/tuple index:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> ('a', 'b')[True]  # True == 1
'b'
>>> ('a', 'b')[1<2]  # 1<2 == True == 1
'b'
>>> ('a', 'b')[2<1]  # 2<1 == False == 0
'a'
```

For `dict` keys, it is similar, but the type coercion is not even needed:

```
>>> {True: 'a', False: 'b'}[1<2]  # 1<2 == True
'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your misconception might be regarding   a < b   .

In all these cases the boolean result of evaluating  a < b  is used as a key for the object in before.

In the case of

```
print( (b, a) [a < b] )
```

and

```
print((lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]())
```

the object is a tuple containing either the variables themselves or very simple anonymus functions, that return these variables.

In the case of

```
print({True: a, False: b} [a < b])
```

the expression is evaluated and used as  a key for the dictionary, which has both True and False as keys. The assumption that this means, that it must be an older Python version is incorrect thoug, because a  dictionary does not represent a reassignment of values, but is merely a data structure, where a key maps to a value. True and False are valid keys and this circumstance is precisely, what is being used here.

Finally:

```
 print( a if a < b else b )
```

Is a nice and concise may of expressing the same thing and in fact the line of code I would use in this case