# what is this python syntax called condensed arithmetic if/else

Tags: python

I saw the following code that converts unsigned number to 2's complement.
Never seen this kind of syntax before.

seems like a condensed if/else but I am unable to look it up in google cuz i don't know its name.

```
def core(x,N):
    x = int(x)
    return (x + (0,-2**N) [x >= 2**(N-1)])
```

Comment: `int(True)` and `int(False)` should help you understand ... its called "array indexing" i guess ... using a ternary statement is probably preferable from a readability standpoint `x + (-2**N if x >= 2**(N-1) else 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional expression/ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186632/conditional-expression-ternary-operator)

Comment: OMG, I see it now. Its some sneaky code. I thought it was some fancy new python syntax. :-D