# Python Scopes (globals and local) and Unbound Error

Tags: python, function, scope

```
var = 100

def function():
    print(f"Printing var from outer_func(): {var}")
    var = 1  # There will be no error If you comment this

function()
```

While printing, why "var" variable can't just be taken from a global scope like it is done when I comment out the line 6 with the assignment 1 to var?
Isn't python interpreter read code line by line? If so, how can it know whether var is assigned or not when I assign it after printing?

Can you please explain what is going on here? Thank you in advance

Comment: No, it doesn't execute the code line by line. When it's compiling the function, it scans it to see which variables are assigned, and makes them local variables unless there's a `global` or `nonlocal` declaration.

Comment: _"Isn't python interpreter read code line by line?"_ No, Python isn't read line by line. It's parsed and compiled to bytecode all in one go. See also [Is Python interpreted, or compiled, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889747/11082165).

Comment: The simple answer is, this was a design decision made in the original implementation of Python.  Some disagree with it, but it is what it is and you must learn to recognize it.